# Meteor app only calls 10.0.2.2:3000 on device regardless of process.env settings

Tags: cordova, meteor, build, apk

I have been working on this app for 8 months and am reaching the end, except for this ip address issue. I cannot prevent my app from calling 10.0.2.2:3000 on an Android device, even after implementing the suggestions from others who have had the same problem. I don't know what else to try. One thing I should mention is that using a browser I can connect to the server without a problem and run the app.

On the server side I have set the following environment variables:
Meteor.startup(() => {
    var ROOT_URL = 'https://myapp:443';

```
Meteor.absoluteUrl.defaultOptions.rootUrl = ROOT_URL;
process.env.ROOT_URL = ROOT_URL;
process.env.MOBILE_ROOT_URL = ROOT_URL;
process.env.MOBILE_DDP_URL = ROOT_URL;
process.env.DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL = ROOT_URL;
```

}

Next I ran:
- mupx setup 
- mupx deploy

The mup.json settings are:
  "env": {
    "ROOT_URL": "https://myapp.com:443",
  },
  "ssl": {
    "certificate": "./.deploy/bundle.crt",
    "key": "./.deploy/privkey.pem",
    "port": 443
  },

Then I build the apk using using:
- meteor build ../myAppProduction --server https://myapp.com:443

So far everything work fine. Then I copy the apk generated by the Meteor build to an android device. Installed and ran the app. The app tries to connect, but when I checked the ip address it is attempting to connect to on the device it is 10.0.2.2:3000.

I would really appreciate some help on this. I have been working on it for 3 days with no luck.

Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 0):

If you search for 10.0.2.2 on meteor sources, you find:

```
   16:    if (/Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
   17        // When Android app is emulated, it cannot connect to localhost,
   18:       // instead it should connect to 10.0.2.2
   19        // (unless we're using an http proxy; then it works!)
   20        if (!__meteor_runtime_config__.httpProxyPort) {
   21:         __meteor_runtime_config__.ROOT_URL = (__meteor_runtime_config__.ROOT_URL || '').replace(/localhost/i, '10.0.2.2');
   22:         __meteor_runtime_config__.DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL = (__meteor_runtime_config__.DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL || '').replace(/localhost/i, '10.0.2.2');
   23        }
   24     }
```

The IP Address 10.0.2.2 is something fix programmed into meteor / android app.

On my site this only happend (as defined in source) when using "localhost" as identifier to ROOT_URL. So I just replace that with "127.0.0.1"

Maybe this will help you as well

Tom

Comment: Thanks Tom, I'm trying that now. I found some 60 places where 10.0.2.2 is referenced in the Cordova code, I did a global replace.

Comment: I have tried editing the cordova index file, but it gets rebuilt and replaced when meteor build gets run. I have also tries to use the apktool, without success. It seems like others have had success adding process.env.ROOT_URL = ROOT_URL;
process.env.MOBILE_ROOT_URL = ROOT_URL;
process.env.MOBILE_DDP_URL = ROOT_URL;

Comment: Can someone that has launched a meteor app on the Google Play Store please share their deployment process and their use of environment variables?  Thanks, Mark

Comment: I removed the SSL and got it working. Still not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out. Once I ran meteor --production it worked with ssl.